# Как отличить момент появления активити от поворота его?

Tags: android

При нажатии home и повторном возврате в приложение активити пересоздается, но и при повороте девайса оно пересоздается также. Как отличить программно эти два события?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    }
```

при повороте

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    }
```

при возврате, или onPause, или onCreate и проверить bundle на null

Comment: все верно, так и делал, но странная весчь: если нажать back прога закроется, запустить ее - вызывается onCreate. Потом нажать home прога тоже исчезает с экрана, запускаем ее - но теперь onCreate не вызывается.

Мне нужно как-то отследить каждое появление активити на экране (но НЕ поворот!).

Comment: добавил матчасть

Comment: все так и есть. Чтобы отследить появление активити после нажатия home нужно использовать onStart (если я правильно понял?).  Но как тогда в onStart отличить момент от поворота (там нет Bundle savedInstanceState)?